# button click() does not provide any response

Tags: java, html, authentication, htmlunit

I'm having issues with logging into specific website via HtmlUnit methods.
The site form's submit button looks like this:

```html
<td>
    <input type="button" value="Login!" onclick="encPass(UTM_STUDIO_ADMIN);" class="normalButton">
</td>
```

Mine code snippet:

```java
final HtmlButtonInput submitLogin = form.getInputByValue("Login!");

HtmlPage returnPage = submitLogin.click();
System.out.println(returnPage.asText());
```

Yet, it prints the logging site with username and password fields fulfilled, that's all.

WebClient config:

```java
wclient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
wclient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
wclient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
wclient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
wclient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
wclient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

I've been already trying to log via my own added button, and played with ideas of waiting, enabling JS, redirecting etc., but I'm new in the topic so it does not guarantee I can uncheck any ideas as already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is of type button (not submit). In this case the browser renders only a button but the application developer is responsible for doing something if the user clicks the button. In you case the button will trigger some javascript.

But you have disabled Javscript by

```
wclient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Maybe your problem goes away if you enable javascript.

In general it is a good idea to start with the default setting when facing any problems. The defaults are set in a way to be as close as possible to the real browsers.

Comment: `<button>` is Button, but `<input type="button">` is HtmlButtonInput

Comment: ButtonInput is still clickable (checked in different case). Enabling JS didn't help in any case or even made it worse as it had huge problems with some missing/erroneous site's code.